# Can a copy constructor have a non-const lvalue parameter?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
class Complex{
    int x,y;
    
    public:
    
    void setdata(int x,int y)
    {
        this->x=x;this->y=y;
    }
    Complex add(Complex &c)
    {
        Complex temp;
        temp.x=this->x + c.x;
        temp.y=this->y + c.y;
        return temp; 
    }
    Complex(Complex &c) // copy constructor
    {
        x=c.x; y=c.y;
    }
    Complex() // Simple default constructor
    {

    }
    void showdata()
    {cout<< this->x <<" "<< this->y;}
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1; c1.setdata(3,4);
    Complex c2=c1; 
    Complex c3 = c1.add(c2);
    //c3.showdata();
    cout<<"\n"<<Complex::v;
    return 0;
}
```

`Complex c2=c1;` This is fine with compiler.
while `Complex c3 = c1.add(c2);` creates errors namely:

- class `Complex` has no suitable copy constructor.
- cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type `Complex &` to an rvalue of type `Complex`.

Is this related to memory being released after the temp variable is destroyed or something else as i am not able to understand the errors prescribed by Compiler as mentioned above?

Comment: `Complex(Complex &c)` -> `Complex(Complex const& c)`

Comment: you should make things `const` by default. This will make the error go away, but to explain the issue a bit more is needed i guess

Comment: Aha! Issue resolved! But I don't know how this 'const' magic resolved the issue

Comment: Think of `void f(int &x) { x=2; }`, which involves a non-const reference argument. We can call `f(y)` (and `y` will be assigned 2) but we can not call `f(1+1)`: the assignment `1+1=2` would make no sense. Hence, C++ forbids calling `f` with an rvalue expression like `1+1`. If we had instead `void f(const int& x) {...}` then C++ would allow `f(1+1)` since `x` is constant, and in the `...` we can not assign it. Hence, a copy ctor should always take a const reference `T(const T& other)` so that is can also be called with rvalue expressions of type T.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed You should definitely invest in some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: *Can a copy constructor have a non-const lvalue parameter?*  **Yes**, however then that precludes using a temporary as an argument.  General guidance for reference parameters is:  if the object parameter is not being modified, then prefer using a *const reference* which allows the argument to be an lvalue or an rvalue.

Comment: Much gratitude to everyone who contributed. Almost all responses prompted me to learn about rvalue/lvalue thing in c++, which is crucial to properly understand what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that the `add` member function returns an **rvalue expression** of type `Complex` and you're trying to bind a **non-const lvalue reference `Complex&`** to that **rvalue**.

You can **solve** this error by replacing `Complex(Complex &c)` with:

```
Complex(const Complex &c) //const added here
```

Note the `const` added in the above statement. Now, the parameter of the copy constructor is a **reference to `const` Complex** which can be bound to an **rvalue**.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question in the title is: yes, the copy-constructor *can* have a non-const argument. From the [C++20 draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/releases/tag/n4861)

> 11.4.4.2 Copy/move constructors [class.copy.ctor]
>
> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments